# TIMEPICKER JQUERY DEMO

Tags: jquery

how to Bind the Date Timer to text box

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Click-2-Call.aspx.cs" Inherits="Click_2_Call" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Click2Call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .numbers
        {
            width: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold; /* options are normal, bold, bolder, lighter */
            font-style: normal; /* options are normal or italic */
            color: #3d3d3d; /* change color using the hexadecimal color codes for HTML */
        }
        .title
        {
            width: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bold; /* options are normal, bold, bolder, lighter */
            color: #3d3d3d; /* change color using the hexadecimal color codes for HTML */
        }
        .numbers1
        {
            width: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold; /* options are normal, bold, bolder, lighter */
            font-style: normal; /* options are normal or italic */
            color: #999; /* change color using the hexadecimal color codes for HTML */
        }
        .style2
        {
            height: 28px;
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
        .style19
        {
            width: 70px;
            height: 12px;
        }
        .style24
        {
            width: 70px;
            height: 32px;
        }
        .style37
        {
            width: 221px;
            height: 32px;
        }
        .style38
        {
            width: 221px;
            height: 12px;
        }
        .style42
        {
            width: 70px;
            height: 11px;
        }
        .style43
        {
            width: 221px;
            height: 11px;
        }
        .style47
        {
            height: 10px;
        }
        .style48
        {
            width: 221px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        .Border
        {
            width: 313px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            height: 320px;
            margin-right: 14px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            background: url(Image/backgroundimage1.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: 440px;
        }

        .style49
        {
            height: 10px;
            width: 70px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body onload="countdown(yr, m, d, hr, min)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="Border">
        <table style="width: 313px; margin-top: 0px; height: 320px; margin-right: 14px;">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClick2Call" runat="server" Text="Click2Call" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    <img alt="Imga" src="Image/smart.jpg" width="25px" height="25px" style="float: right" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style24">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name :" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style37">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style19">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Text="Number :" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style38">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumber"
                        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="Please Enter the Number" ValidationGroup="vgCallMe"
                        ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumber" OnServerValidate="TextValidate"
                        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="Please Enter Only Digit or Numberic value or Atleast 10 digit"
                        ValidationGroup="vgCallMe" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style19">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email :" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style38">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" OnServerValidate="EmailValidate"
                        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="Please Enter Valid Email Id..." ValidationGroup="vgCallMe"
                        ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style19">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text="Location :" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style38">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"
                        Font-Names="Tahoma"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style19">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLanguage" runat="server" Text="Language :" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style38">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="207px" AutoPostBack="false"
                        Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8.25pt">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">English</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Hindi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Marathi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Punjabi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Gujrati</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Bengali</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="7">telgu</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="8">kanada</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style42">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="Time :" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Bold="True"
                        Font-Size="8.25pt"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style43">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"
                        Font-Names="Tahoma"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr`enter code here`>
                <td class="style49">
                </td>
                <td class="style48">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCallMe" runat="server" Text="Call Me" Width="81px" ValidationGroup="vgCallMe"
                        OnClick="btnCallMe_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" Width="90px" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style47" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcopyRight" Text="©2014@SmartConnect Technologies Pvt. Ltd." runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 295px">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDisplayMessage" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </div>  
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtTime").datetimepicker();
            });        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi please help it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to that textbox. Because id will change at the time of rendering as it has the property `runat=server`

html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" CssClass="txtTime" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="205px" MaxLength="500"
                    Font-Names="Tahoma"></asp:TextBox>
```

then you can use like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".txtTime").datetimepicker();
        });
```

**Edit**

Change the order of script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Because jquery.ui need jquery. In your case, jquery is not there at the time of executing the jquery.ui. That makes error.

Comment: but why dear can u explain to me

Comment: hi could help me how to give style

Comment: <style type="text/css">
/* css for timepicker */
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header{ margin-bottom: 8px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl{ text-align: left; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt{ height: 25px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd{ margin: -25px 0 10px 65px; }
.ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
</style>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="JS/StyleSheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: hi please help me after adding

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

Comment: what is the problem?? is the calender is not aligned?